checkbox Playwright - check() vs setChecked(true)
According to Playwright Docs, there are two main methods for handling with checkbox elements.
I'm trying to understand what is the difference between these methods - locator.check and locator.setChecked when it set to true.
// check()
await page.getByRole('checkbox').check();

// VS

// setChecked(true)
await page.getByRole('checkbox').setChecked(true);

// (same for `uncheck()` vs `setChecked(false)`)

I've checked the docs and it looks like they're basically the same.
I've checked their functionality and it seems like they do the same.
Is there any difference? maybe a different purpose?

Looks identical. Possibly an addition to match other "setX"

For me check() can only check a radio button or checkbox but setChecked() can also untick a checkbox by false

OK, I thought this is obvious, but I've specified the true value in the question.

locator.check

locator.setCheck

So, judging by the documentation, locator.check will throw if the element is detached from DOM at any moment during action, whereas locator.setCheck will retry in that scenario.

Please see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? and Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors. Those screenshots of text should be provided as blockquoted plain text so they're readable and accessible. Thanks.

@ggorlen I guess he provided screenshots in order to mark those differences in red, thanks for the detailed answer anyway!

I think this is a great Answer, thank you @Lajos Arpad!

@VishalAggarwal happy to help. Yes, the screenshots had the goal of emphasizing the difference. I have also written a short summary for those who would have difficulties with checking the image.

They are basically the same setChecked is calling check internally
async setChecked(checked: boolean, options?: channels.ElementHandleCheckOptions) {
    if (checked)
      await this.check(options);
    else
      await this.uncheck(options);
  }

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/69404561f9d09e045fd72f879cd96dabee016176/packages/playwright-core/src/client/locator.ts#L308-L313

This is interesting, did you saw the answer above? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78676578/19574650
